# REST: Updating multiple records

Tags: json, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

I need to update multiple records using a single HTTP request. An example is selecting a list of emails and marking them as 'Unread'. What is the best (Restful) way to achieve this?

The way I doing right now is, by using a sub resource action

`PUT http://example.com/api/emails/mark-as-unread`

(in the body)

`{ids:[1,2,3....]}`

Comment: If you do not use this "update all" function for anything else I think this is good option but if you use it then create another route for updating by ids, that's how I would do it.

Comment: Do you mean something like `http://example.com/api/emails/bulk-update` and then passing an array of objects?

Comment: Yea something like that, choose route which describes your function best

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create an algorithm-endpoint, like

```
http://example.com/api/emails/mark-unread
```

`bulk-update` is an algorithm name, a noun. It gets to be the endpoint name in REST, the list of ids are arguments to this algorithm. Typically people send them as URL query arguments in the `POST` call like

```
http://example.com/api/emails/mark-unread?ids=1,2,3,4
```

This is very safe, as POST is non-idempotent and you need not care about any side effects. You might decide differently and if your bulk update carries entire state of such objects opt for `PUT`

```
http://example.com/api/emails/bulk-change-state
```

then you would have to put the actual state into the body of the http call.
I'd prefer a bunch of simple algo like `mark-unread?ids=1,2,3,4` rather than one monolithic `PUT` as it helps with debugging, transparent in logs etc

Comment: From what I read from others about RESTful, the concept is that all URIs represents resources (i.e. nouns), there should be no verb in any part of the URI.  Thus, introducing "mark-unread" seems not quite RESTful way.

Comment: @JohnnyWong Although it does look like it's a verb you can think of "mark-unread" as an algorithm name to avoid confusion

Comment: @Johnny Wong, then how would you deal with operations like 'mark all as read' on a paginated resource?

Comment: @Ledorub Your question depends on how you want the parameters to represent back that-page's emails - whether by listing all ids or not. I don't have a fixed suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

I read this site - http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#actions - and it suggests to use an "actions" sub-collection. e.g.

POST http://example.com/api/emails/actions

(in the body)

{"type":"mark-as-unread", "ids":[1,2,3....]}

### Quotes from the referenced webpage:

> Sometimes, it is required to expose an operation in the API that inherently is non RESTful. One example of such an operation is where you want to introduce a state change for a resource, but there are multiple ways in which the same final state can be achieved, ...  A great example of this is the difference between a “power off” and a “shutdown” of a virtual machine.
>
> As a solution to such non-RESTful operations, an “actions” sub-collection can be used on a resource. Actions are basically RPC-like messages to a resource to perform a certain operation. The “actions” sub-collection can be seen as a command queue to which new action can be POSTed, that are then executed by the API. ...
>
> It should be noted that actions should only be used as an exception, when there’s a good reason that an operation cannot be mapped to one of the standard RESTful methods. ...

Answer (score 2):

It a bit complicated to get array of models into an action method as argument. The easiest approach is to form a json string from your client and POST all that to the server (to your action mehtod). You can adopt the following approach

Say your email model is like this:

```
public class Email
{
    public int EmailID {get; set;}
    public int StatusID {get; set;}
    // more properties
}
```

So your action method will take the form:

```
public bool UpdateAll(string EmailsJson)
{
    Email[] emails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Emails[]>(EmailsJson);
    foreach(Email eml in emails)
    {
        //do update logic
    }
}
```

Using Json.NET to help with the serialization.

On the client you can write the ajax call as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api/emailsvc/updateall',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        EmailsJson: JSON.stringify([{
            ID: 1,
            StatusID:2,
            //...more json object properties.
            },
            // more json objects
            ])
        },
    success:function(result){
        if(result)
            alert('updated successfully');
    });
```